# How to call button in other class using kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How do i call this function in other class and if i implement companion object it cause an error

```
class CommonMethods{
private fun onPressFacebookLogin() {
    btn_fb_login.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        // Login
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile", "email"))
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook token: " + loginResult.accessToken.token)
                    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook onCancel.")
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook onError.")
                }
            })
    })
}
```

}

Comment: just use fun onPressFacebookLogin(btn_fb_login:View) and pass the current UI button in that function

Comment: now when i implement that it shows another error 
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile", "email"))
 startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))

Comment: please pass the context like btn_fb_login.context

Comment: What type of error you are having now can you share logs??

Comment: @DeePanShu where did i spicific insert the code of context ?

Comment: try this   btn_fb_login.context .startActivity(Intent(btn_fb_login.context , MainActivity::class.java))

Comment: now after applying that code this will happen
(Intent(btn_fb_login.context, MainActivity::class.java)) this line is error 

additional information 
the applicationContext before is from this class
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MyFacebookApp : Application() {
    //    Facebook
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(applicationContext)
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this)
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code and try again to start activity like this

```
    object CommonMethods{
                       private fun onPressFacebookLogin(btn_fb_login:View, fragment:Fragment? = null,activity:Activity? = null) {
    
                        val mContext = btn_fb_login.context
                        btn_fb_login.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                // Login
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

            
               if(activity!=null)
         LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, listOf("public_profile", "email"))
else if(fragment!=null)
         LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(fragment, listOf("public_profile", "email"))
else
return
           LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                    override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook token: " + loginResult.accessToken.token)
                        mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }
    
                    override fun onCancel() {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook onCancel.")
                    }
    
                    override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook onError.")
                    }
                })
        })
    }
    
    }
```

Pass your button from activity Like this from activity:

```
CommonMethods.onPressFacebookLogin(your_button_view, activity = this)
```

Pass your button from activity Like this from fragment:

```
CommonMethods.onPressFacebookLogin(your_button_view, fragment = this)
```

Comment: that line is resolve but this line is still error
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile", "email"))

Comment: Check for the edits and explore if any issue then pls ask

Comment: in the activity:Activity = null  the null had red underlien and my dependecies affected now.

Comment: actually last two arguments is nullable check now

Comment: Any way Thankyou for your efforts have great day.

Answer (score 0):

this is my new code the line
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile", "email"))
and this line is the error
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

```
class CommonMethods{
lateinit var callbackManager : CallbackManager

companion object callFacebook{
    fun onPressFacebookLogin(btn_fb_login:View,) {
        val mContext = btn_fb_login.context
        btn_fb_login.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            // Login
            var callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile", "email"))
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                    override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook token: " + loginResult.accessToken.token)
                        mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }

                    override fun onCancel() {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook onCancel.")
                    }

                    override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook onError.")
                    }
                })
        })
    }

}
fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    callbackManager?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

}